# Angular/Google Analytics ng-repeat list

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics

Quick question, I can't find anywhere how to send the selected list element in an ng-repeat to GA. Maybe with Angularitics etc?

My thinking so far was something like:

```
 <li ng-repeat="x in x" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'link', 'selected', $parent.x;">
```

The problem is how do I send the "$parent.x" through as the GA category

Can't seem to get it to work though. Thanks!

Comment: if `ga` function is there in a scope then you could use `ng-click="ga(....)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of Angular is that it is a MVC. This being the case, the HTML doesn't have an idea what $parent is and you need to have a common 'scope' between the HTML and the Javascript. This is why there is the built in $scope so if in my controller I had `$scope.newX = $parent.x` then in my HTML I can pass `ng-click="myFunction(newX)"` and it will pass it the value of the $scope.newX

Comment: Yeah, was just getting confused with injecting GA as normal I think. Thanks for clearing it up!